# Convert date String "Thu Oct 15 05:19:21 XXX 2015" to "yyyy-MM-dd" with JAVA

Tags: java, date, datetime, format

I am new to java and I'm trying to make a format conversion dates

I want convetir a date, "Thu Oct. 15 2015 5:19:21 XXX 2015" string type ... this format "yyyy-MM-dd"

Try "SimpleDateFormat" but not worked.
resulting in "Unparseable date"

```
      Input:
          String = "Thu Oct 15 05:19:21 XXX 2015"

      Output:
          String="2015-10-15"
```

sorry for my English...

This is My code :

```
public static String formatDate(String string) {
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = format.parse(string);
        getDateFormated(date, false);
        return getDateFormated(date, false);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {

    }
    return "";
} 

public static String getDateFormated(Date date,boolean withFormatHour) {
    if (date != null) {
        String format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        if (withFormatHour) {
            format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        }
        return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Have u tried anything urself? 
Show us ur effort and explain what specifically did not work in ur code. As is, it appears that u r just asking us to do ur homework for u.

Comment: Show your code. Without any actual effort shown it sounds like you're just asking us to do it for you. There are lots of resources available about parsing and formatting dates in java.

Comment: Sorry ....added the code

Comment: Have a look at SimpleDateFormat (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @user3546669 Still don't see any code.

Answer (score 1):

You parse it and reformat it:

```
String input = "Thu Oct 15 05:19:21 XXX 2015";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'XXX' yyyy").parse(input);
String output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(date);
```